# Force information_schema.tables to return sorted by table name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, information-schema

I am trying to perform tasks within my ERP system's admin tool.  The tool interfaces with the MS-Sql Server that is housing the ERP's data.  Any time I want to perform an action on a table via the ERP system's admin tool, it runs a

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
```

and populates a scrollable list with all of the tables that comprise the ERP system.  The issue is, this list is not sorted and I do not have the ability to sort it on the client side.  There are 3,700 *(no exaggeration)* tables.  Scrolling through the unordered list and finding 1 table I need takes literally 20-30 minutes on average, depending on where the table is in the list.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I can either force MS-Sql Server to return the table in a sorted fashion or rebuild the table alphabetically?

I do not have the ability to modify the query that gets sent from inside of the proprietary tool - at the end of the day, it will only send `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES`

So is there any way that I can force the result of that query to return the list sorted?  Can I create a view that will take precedence?  Again, the query **cannot** be changed.

Comment: Nope, if you want the result ordered you need an `order by` on the results. Is your admin tool browser based? If so you could use a browser addon to add ordering and filtering to the table such as https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/tabletools2/

Comment: No, it's not browser based.  I wish.  Do you think it's possible to rebuild that info table in order?  (I know it's probably not advisable to mess with that table, but I'm desperate.  Last night I needed to hunt down 9 tables and after two hours I had only found 5 of 9)

Comment: No, that's a view not a table anyway and it joins multiple base tables. You'll just get them in whatever order the execution plan leads to.

Comment: Can the view be modified?

Comment: No, this is a system view that is part of the resource database. There is no supported way of altering it.

Comment: If you were to log in to SSMS and do your own `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` there's probably a good chance you will get the same execution plan as your application though and (assuming the order you see in both places is the same) you could paste it into Excel to make it easier to search and once you've located its position there it may make it easier to find in the application.

Comment: It's pretty cool that my colleague and I discussed this exact approach earlier today.  It is, in fact, in the same order in the app and in SSMS.  I was really hoping someone would have a magic solution, but it looks like we'll be taking your suggested approach.  Thanks for all of your help and input!

Answer (score 1):

From the [SQL Server Books Online](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188385.aspx):

> The order in which rows are returned in a result set are not
>   guaranteed unless an ORDER BY clause is specified.

Probably not the answer you want to hear but this is the way all ANSI SQL compliant DBMS systems operate.  A table, as well as views, are unordered sets of rows so outermost queries must specify `ORDER BY` for deterministic ordering of result sets.